# MySQL fulltext performance solution

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search

How to deal with queries like :

```
select ... from ... where match(field1) against('someA') and match(field2) against('someB') limit 50
```

If results returned by condition match(field1) against('someA') & match(field2) against('someB') are both huge,the entire query will be very,very slow.

A solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create another `FULLTEXT` index for the two columns `field1` and `field2`.  Then search for both search terms at once with:

```
MATCH(field1, field2) AGAINST ('+someA +someB') IN BOOLEAN MODE
```

Of course, this could find rows where `field1` contains both search terms, and `field2` contains neither.  I'm not sure of the exact requirements of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) would solve this problem efficiently for you.  Sphinx provides powerful fulltext search capability.  I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're trying to do, but it sounds close.